# Create iframe and then maninuplate its contents

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

What I want to do is open an iframe, pointing to another website, and then submit a form on that website.

This is obviously cross-origin, so Chrome (and I assume other browsers) doesn't allow me to do stuff to the contents of the iframe, once it's loaded.

So I've tried doing it in a Chrome extension.  I'm getting a similar error:

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://amnacjaocbabmgfjcbmgbhikfedaanmo" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.example.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "chrome-extension", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?  I can post more details on my current method, if necessary.  But, I'm open to other suggestions (e.g. opening a new tab and doing the work in there, etc.).  Anyone know of something that will work without getting some kind of security error?

EDIT:  So far the best solution I've come up with is using a background script to open a new tab, and use content scripts to manipulate its content.  It would be really nice if I could just load the page into an iframe, and then send content scripts just to that iframe, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

Answer (score -2):

In the page header of your embedded page, include the following header:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM www.example.com
```

This bypasses at least Chrome and Firefox. Your mileage may vary on IE.

Comment: I don't have control over the embedded page (i.e. I can't add a header entry).

Comment: Also, I think X-Frame-Options just says "this page can be embedded".  I can already embed it, I just can't manipulate it once it's loaded.